# Change the title of the sidebar option for /questions to Questions (as on MSE and MSO)

Tags: feature-request, left-navigation

On MSE and here on MSO, the title of the sidebar option for [`/questions`](/questions) is "Questions":

[image]

On Stack Overflow, it's "Stack Overflow":

[image]

Respecting that navigation design is complicated and has lots of competing constraints, this seems unclear to say the least. :-) I literally went looking for the questions link, not suspecting that that was it until I happened to see the menu on MSE.

Please change it to Questions, as on MSE and MSO. It's:

- More clear
- More consistent (consistency being an important UI goal): clicking "Stack Overflow" in the banner takes me to the landing page, so I expect a "Stack Overflow" link in the nav to do the same (despite the presence of a "Home" link)

Comment: Another bad option could be to change *Public* into *Stack Overflow* (as I assume it needs to indicate you're not in a team) if anyone feels Stack Overflow should be kept there. That at least makes the UI consistent. But, hey, I'm not an UX expert, not even novice, I only use this site.

Comment: @rene - Good point about what it's trying to differentiate, though; I've riffed that into an answer.

Answer (score 16):

Keying off [rene's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369416/change-the-title-of-the-sidebar-option-for-questions-to-questions-as-on-mse-an/369420#comment599800_369416), I assume "Stack Overflow" is there to differentiate those links from the Teams links (although I suspect that even if Teams is wildly successful, Teams users will be something like 0.01% of all users, and of course there are all those non-user-visitors). If so:

- Stack Overflow

  - [Home](https://stackoverflow.com)
  - [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)
  - [Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)
  - [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users)
  - [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab)
- Teams

  - [+ Create Team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams)

Or if it really makes sense for Home (`https://stackoverflow.com`) not to be in the "Stack Overflow" category (to me as currently one of the ~99.99% non-Teams users, it doesn't, but I could be missing a subtlety):

- [Home](https://stackoverflow.com)
- Stack Overflow

  - [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)
  - [Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)
  - [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users)
  - [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab)
- Teams

  - [+ Create Team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams)

Comment: Another benefit of this could be that you can add / have quick links to Meta and maybe your other communities (that are now hidden in the hamburger menu at the top right). That at least would alleviate some of the *useless-(n/m)ess* or *too much white space* arguments seen around all Meta's ...

Comment: I'd also like an option to hide/turn off everything "Team" related.

Comment: What about the Users link?

Comment: @DonaldDuck - Doh! Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @j08691 The only thing teams related I know of is in the left sidebar, right? or am I missing some? That could easily be removed with a userscript or adblocker.