# Where is the newest tab in SO?

Tags: support, design

In Stack Overflow the `newest` tab is missing since the new update.

Where is the new tab? How to see the newly asked questions? Is there any other way to access it?

This is how the page looks now.

[image]

Comment: Related: [*Change the title of the sidebar option for /questions to Questions (as on MSE and MSO)*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369416/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the side-bar click on Stack Overflow (the item with the globe next to it, right under public):

[image]

Alternatively, if you have the side bar hidden, navigate to the top bar, and click the button that looks like three bars, then press on the Stack Overflow item:

[image]

This will bring you to the "All Questions" screen, where you can select "Newest":

[image]

Comment: Ehh.. Is it just me, or now stuff like this feels much less intuitive then they should...

Comment: Such a painful UI... *groan*

Comment: @Skipper It's not just you, it's a terrible design. They have split functionality between two separate pages that show more or less the same content. Problem is some of the functionality you want on one view is only available on the other.