# Why is the "Questions" button in the main menu missing only in the desktop version of the Stack Overflow site?

Tags: bug, mobile-web, question-lists

I noticed that in mobile version of Stack Overflow I have a "Questions" button that opens the [All Questions page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions), and in the desktop version of Stack Overflow I don't have such an option in the main menu. It looks completely OK, as the mobile version differs a lot to be more convenient and friendly-looking on mobile devices.

But then I noticed that the Meta Stack Exchange site has the "Questions" button in the main menu ([All Questions page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions)) in both mobile and desktop versions.

I personally think that "Questions" button is useless for the Stack Overflow site as people may find it much more convenient to search for specific questions or tags rather than scrolling *all* questions without filtering. So I think there is no sense in that button in the Stack Overflow menu. But I can't understand why it is present in the mobile Stack Overflow.

[image: Desktop vs mobile]

Also, one more thing that seems weird to me is the titles on the Home pages. The desktop versions have the "Top Questions" title, but mobile versions have the "All Questions" title for the same page. Clicking on "Questions" on mobile leads to another [All Questions page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions) with the same "All Questions" title, but it is different (has other filtering options at least).

Are these bugs or features?

Comment: I guess that's because of the team integration on the main site. The "Stack Overflow" links brings you to the page you are looking for

Comment: @BDL Oh, really. Thank you. And what about titles?

Comment: Related feature request: [Change the title of the sidebar option for /questions to Questions (as on MSE and MSO)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369416/2675154)